# retrieving a datalist created in one void and displaying it in another

Tags: c#

I have a question about calling data from one method into another.

Basically I have tasked myself with condensing and simplifying my code. In this scenario I am connecting to a .MDB file and reading 1 bit of data from it. Originally I had the connection string in all the spots where it was needed, but after learning more and more about classes and stuff I was informed that copying and pasting is bad. so I wanted to take my connection string and make it...it's own void then call to it with variables from the needed spots. The problem is how to return the datalist retrieved from the DB? here is the code as I have it now which works fine.

```
string directory = @"C:\";
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "Rameses-*");
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string foldername in folders)
            {
                using (var conection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + foldername + "\\Program\\random.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=******"))
                {
                    conection.Open();
                    var query = "Select u_company From t_user";
                    var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conection);
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dataList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    conection.Close();
                }
            }
            error_handling(" Alternate Profiles Loaded into Selector");
            profselect.DataSource = dataList;
            profselect.SelectedText = dataList.Last();
```

but I thought that I would be able to take the connection out of it's current spot and do something like this however now I can't get the datalist from the inital connection for my drop down. Any Suggestions?

```
        //Database Connection Base Function
    public static void database_link(string query, string foldername)
    {
        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
        using (var conection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + foldername + "\\Program\\Random.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"))
        {
            conection.Open();
            var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conection);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dataList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            conection.Close();
        }
    }

    // Ramdata check and load from files and database
    private void ramdata_check(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string directory = @"C:\";
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "Myapp-*");
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string foldername in folders)
            {
                database_link("Select u_company From t_user", foldername);
            }
            error_handling(" Alternate Profiles Loaded into Selector");
            profselect.DataSource = dataList;
            profselect.SelectedText = dataList.Last();
        }
        catch
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the shared connection call a void: make it create the connection, open it and return it. A [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will close the connection for you when it completes so you don't need to manually close it:

```
public OleDbConnection OpenConnection()
{
      var result = new OleDbConnection("My special connection string here"))
     result.Open()
     return result;
 }

public List<string> void DoSomethingWithConnection()
 {
    using (var connection = OpenConnection());
    {
        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("DoSomethingHere", connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dataList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }

        return dataList;
    // The connection is automatically closed when the 
    // code exits the using block.
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent. I changed it around a bit but your though there helped me out!! thanks